# Release build seems to skip .babelrc

Tags: javascript, react-native, build, babeljs, lightstreamer

I'm having issue with building my release apk.
Problem is occurred when I installed lightstreamer-client module.
On their site they say you should add this line to .babelrc:

"ignore": [
    "./node_modules/lightstreamer-client/lightstreamer"
  ]

I added it and it solved the problem for debug apk version 
but it remains when I try to build release apk.
To me it seems as it ignores .babelrc.

Additional info: 
It breaks during :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets,
error location: \node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:590

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked same question on Lightstreamer forum and got answer.
Shortly, they told me to use version 7.0.7 because it is strict mode compatible.

So, this is solution that works for me. If someone knows solution for skipping some non strict mode compatible modules please add your answer as well.

Here is link to forum post:
[Forum post](https://forums.lightstreamer.com/showthread.php?5555-React-Native-release-build-fails)